# FFmpeg blend mode with video green screen

Tags: video, ffmpeg, blend

I am trying to try to de-green the video with FFmpeg. I find using blends with multiply available with the command line:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i green.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v] format=rgba [bg]; [1:v] format=rgba [fg]; [bg][fg] blend=all_mode='multiply':all_opacity=1, format=rgba"
```

[image]

I have a problem with the color of the main video turning green. What do I need to do to solve this problem?

Green screen:
[image]

My video:
[image]

Comment: Share full log and a screenshot of how input.mp4 and green.mp4 look.

Comment: yes I have updated it

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to overlay the green video over the background.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i green.mp4 -filter_complex     \
    '[1:v]colorkey=0x00ff00:0.4:0.2[ckout];[0:v][ckout]overlay[out]' \
    -map '[out]'  -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p res.mp4
```

`00ff00`  is green , `ff0000`  is red

You *must* be sure to choose the right color , for the value of the chromakey.

`0.4` is a similarity factor `0.2` is a opacity factor

PS: More information => https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#colorkey

PPS: To do some testing you can change length of final video by giving a arg `-ts`.

Comment: I tried with chromakey filter but with small details will be lost. Images are not smooth.

Comment: @Lea...FFmpeg did you try wil different value of `similarity` , to cut the time of the conversion you can only generate a small video by specifying a `ts`

Comment: This is great. How to get the green.mp4 to show up at a regular interval, say at every 2minutes? (You know where I am going with this. Adding a thumbs up overlay in a video. Please help.