# FFMPEG - Add a green video overlay at a fixed Interval in a video. How to define the interval?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, overlay, timing

I am trying to add a green screen video overlay on the top of my main video. The green video overlay is like a thumbs up that shows up every few minutes in the video. I have a ffmpeg command that adds the video overlay perfectly. (I got this from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1563712/ffmpeg-blend-mode-with-video-green-screen))

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i green.mp4 -filter_complex     \
       '[1:v]colorkey=0x00ff00:0.4:0.2[ckout];[0:v][ckout]overlay[out]' \
        -map '[out]'  -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p res.mp4
```

However, the green.mp4 show up right at the beginning. But I am trying to add it at a regular intervals. Say 5 minutes, 10 minutes, etc. Something like this.

[image: overlay video at regular interval]

I am even ok with just having it show up once in the video, but at the specified time. It would be nice to have it repeated few times, if possible, and not too complicated.

Comment: Did the answer help?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add proper `enable` property to the filter:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i green.mp4 -filter_complex     \
  "[1:v]colorkey=0x00ff00:0.4:0.2[ckout];[0:v][ckout]overlay=enable='eq(mod(t, 300), 0)'[out]" \
  -map '[out]'  -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p res.mp4
```

- `mod` is used to check divisible intervals by comparing it to `0`. You could instead compare to e.g. `1` (`x`) and use `lt` instead of `eq` to make the overlay appear for longer (`x` seconds).
- `300` because 300 seconds = 5 minutes, so the interval

See documentation for [`enable`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-Timeline-editing) and [supported expressions](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation).

Comment: Thanks. But I get this error, `No option name near 'eq(mod(t, 300), 0)'`.  I am using FFMPEG on Windows. Could the single quote be the issue? BTW, I do not want overlay to appear longer. My overlay video (green.mp4) is about 4 seconds. I need to show this at a given interval multiple times in the video. Thank you.

Comment: What shell? Anyways, fixed a typo, try now